# Extract first non black keyframe with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframe

I'm trying to extract a thumbnail image from a video keyframes using ffmpeg, my command line is:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -s 200x200 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -vsync 0 -f image2 video.jpg
```

But the keyframe it extracts is totally black (the video starts with a black frame i guess) ... is there a way to automatically **extract the first non black keyframe** from a video, **without** seeking to a specific time (i have to manage multiple videos of many durations) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a solution using ffmpeg alone. But if you extract the first few keyframes (by turning up to -vframes 20 for example) they could then be analyzed with ImageMagic. Reducing the image to one grayscale color will it with pick the average gray value from the picture. A command line like

```
convert avatar.jpeg -colors 1 -type grayscale -format '%c' histogram:info:
```

which will produce an output like

```
16384: ( 80, 80, 80) #505050 gray(80)
```

(I used Simone's avatar picture for an example.)  The last number is the most interesting for your case. It expresses how dark the image is, with 0 for ideal black and 255 for pure white. A sed script can easily extract it

```
convert ... | sed 's/^.*(\(.*\))$/\1/'
```

Mix it up with some shell scripting to find the first image that has a gray value higher than a given threshold and use it as the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

With the option thumbnail=num_frame you can choose when you extract a frame, but I don't know if it is possible extract the first non balck keyframe. http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#thumbnail